# Are there risks when running `sudo xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine "/Applications/*.app" `?

Tags: macos, security, malware, gatekeeper

There is an application I really need to use but needs the `sudo xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine` command to run and I am not 100% sure if this app is harmless.

Is there any way to be sure? like scanning the dmg file somehow or something else?

Comment: Why would you need to use `sudo` in order to do that?  For that matter, how did something get into /Applications with the quarantine attribute set?

Comment: @MarcWilson You can easily get an application into `/Applications` with the quarantine attribute. Just drag and drop it there.

Comment: I have a Hazel rule that removes the quarantine attribute from anything that appears in Downloads... I always forget that rule is there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried right clicking the application and choosing Open?

Deleting the quarantine flag circumvents security checks. If you are concerned about the security of the application you should not do this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and yes, I've tried right click > open, but it did not work. I've decided to wait until they add the required license.